# How to respond to a command line prompt in python

Tags: python, subprocess

Hello Dear StackOverflow community, I am having a beginner issue.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['mysql','-u','root','-p'],
                     stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write("password!\n".encode())
p.stdin.close()
```

This is the code I am executing to get the login of the SQL server automated. but it doesn't work. Please help me to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Probably because, like `passwd`, it's not reading stdin.

Comment: but why is it not reading stdin?

Comment: So you can't intercept the password easily

Comment: No at all. Do you have any idea on how can I make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `.encode()` from your write function as the module should handle it for you.